# How to set interval in useEffect in React Functional Component

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'

function App() {

const [list, setList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getdata').then((response) => {
        setList(response.data)
    });
})

return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
            {list.map((val, key) => {
                return <div className="row">{val.Tweet}</div>
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
);}
export default App;
```

The above code fetches the data infinitely from my MySQL database, how can I modify it to fetch the data after a certain interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setInterval

```
useEffect(() => {
   setInterval(
      () => Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getdata').then((response) => {
         setList(response.data)
      }),
      5000 // 5seconds
   )
}, [])
```